# firebreath, cmake and external libraries

Tags: cmake, xml-rpc, firebreath

i'm trying to use this lib in my firebreath project:

http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/

This ext lib got compiled succesfully. I can run the examples too.

In my CMakeLists.txt i put:

```
find_package(XMLRPC REQUIRED c++2)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${XMLRPC})
```

Includes in my cpp file are the same as the example here:

http://xmlrpc-c.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xmlrpc-c/trunk/examples/cpp/xmlrpc_sample_add_client.cpp?view=markup

but when running make, i get:

```
undefined reference to `xmlrpc_c::clientSimple::clientSimple()'
```

I can't understand what's wrong and where :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for CMake's [`FindXMLRPC`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aFindXMLRPC) module, it looks like you should link to `${XMLRPC_LIBRARIES}`.  So change your `target_link_libraries` call to:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${XMLRPC_LIBRARIES})
```